# How to show the bottom of $L^2$ spectrum of Laplacian on hyperbolic plane $H$ is $1/4$?

Tags: differential-geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

For hiperbolic plane $H$, let 
$$
\lambda_0(H)=\inf \frac{\int ||\nabla\phi||^2}{\int\phi^2}
$$
where $\phi$ runs over all non-zero smooth functions on $H$ with compact support in the interior of $H$. How to show $\lambda_0(H)=\frac{1}{4}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this paper by Mckean. He does it in just a few lines on the first page.
http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214429509

Comment: Thanks, but I have hard in your paper. And I ask it in another question, could you help me ? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061131/proof-of-spectrum-of-laplacian-on-hyperbolic-plane

Comment: Help me , I get stuck in this question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062073/eigenvalue-of-delta-on-hyperbolic-plane