# Proof of spectrum of Laplacian on hyperbolic plane.

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

As picture below, what is the mean of $L^2(R^2, dxdy)$ and $L^2(H,y^{-2}dxdy)$ ? I know what is $L^2$ , but I don't know what is $dxdy$. Besides, how to get the equation 1 and 2 ?

Below picture is from this [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214429509).

> [image]

Comment: $dx dy$ and $y^{-2} dxdy$ refer to the measures on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{H}^2$, respectively.  As for (1) and (2), they both come from integration by parts.

Comment: @user197427  Thanks , I understand.